# Sample without repeating string index

Tags: python, random, psychopy

I’m randomly sampling from two master lists to create two shorter test lists in coder before my experiment starts. What I’m trying to do is not sample images that have the same index. So say I `random.sample(List1, 2)` to make `negTest`.

`negTest = ["Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF01_AC.png,0.55,-1.5", "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF06_AC.png,0.55,-1.5"]`

Then I want to make the second list `posTest` from `List2`, but so images with `AF01` and `AF06` in the string don’t get sampled into that list.

I hope someone can provide a solution or point me in the right direction! Let me know if you need any more information.

Here are examples of the two master lists I'm pulling from:
[List1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfDDo.png)
[List2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAS4E.png)

```
list1 = ["Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF01_AC.png,0.55,-1.5",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF02_A0.png,1.3,-1.2",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF03_AC.png,1.05,-1.45",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF05_A0.png,1.05,-1.35",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF06_AC.png,1,-1.55",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF07_A0_copy.png,1.6,-0.8",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF08_AC.png,0.625,-1.7",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF09_A0.png,0.80952381,-1.5238095",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF10_AC.png,0.3,-0.95",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF11_A0.png,1.25,-1.25",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF12_AC.png,0.4,-1.4",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AM01_AO.png,1.15,-1.35",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/CFD-WF-010-014-A.png,0.4,-1.25",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/CFD-WF-011-011-A.png,0.95,-1.35",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/CFD-WF-012-012-A.png,0.1,-1.05",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/CFD-WF-013-015-A.png,0.425,-1.15",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/CFD-WF-015-014-A.png,0.75,-1.2",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/004_o_m_a_a.png,0.85,-1.55",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/006_y_m_a_a.png,1.55,-0.75"
         ]

list2 = [
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF01_HC.png,-0.65,1.2",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF02_HO.png,-0.4,1.7",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF03_HC.png,-0.95,1.05",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF05_HO.png,-@.35,1.45",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF07_HC.png,-0.75,1.05",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF08_HO.png,-0.7,1.4",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF09_HC.png,-0.9,1.35",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF10_H0.png,-0.75,1.575",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF11_HC.png,-0.9,1.3",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF12_H0.png,-0.2,1.35",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AM01_HC.png,-0.75,0.9",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AM02_HO.png,-0.6,1.65",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/CFD-WF-011-003-HO.png,-0.9,1.5",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/CFD-WF-012-004-HC.png,-0.35,1.5",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/CFD-WF-013-006-HO.png,-0.975,1.55",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/CFD-WF-014-009-HC.png,-0.65,0.85",
]
```

Comment: There are fancy ways of doing this.  But the simplest solution is a `while` loop.  Keep on picking two indices until you get values that match whatever your criteria is, and then 'break'.

Answer (score 0):

You could random.sample() the first list, then parse the index from each item in neg_test with a regex, then exclude these from the sample of list2:

```
import random
import re

list1 = ["Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF01_AC.png,0.55,-1.5",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF02_A0.png,1.3,-1.2",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF03_AC.png,1.05,-1.45",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF05_A0.png,1.05,-1.35",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF06_AC.png,1,-1.55",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF07_A0_copy.png,1.6,-0.8",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF08_AC.png,0.625,-1.7",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF09_A0.png,0.80952381,-1.5238095",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF10_AC.png,0.3,-0.95",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF11_A0.png,1.25,-1.25",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF12_AC.png,0.4,-1.4",
         "Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AM01_AO.png,1.15,-1.35",
         ]

list2 = [
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF01_HC.png,-0.65,1.2",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF02_HO.png,-0.4,1.7",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF03_HC.png,-0.95,1.05",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF05_HO.png,-@.35,1.45",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF07_HC.png,-0.75,1.05",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF08_HO.png,-0.7,1.4",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF09_HC.png,-0.9,1.35",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF10_H0.png,-0.75,1.575",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF11_HC.png,-0.9,1.3",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF12_H0.png,-0.2,1.35",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AM01_HC.png,-0.75,0.9",
    "Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AM02_HO.png,-0.6,1.65",
]


def parse_index(s):
    return re.search(r"/([\w-]+)\.png", s).group(1).rstrip("_copy")


neg_test = random.sample(list1, 2)
neg_indexes = {parse_index(item) for item in neg_test}

pos_test = random.sample([item for item in list2 if parse_index(item) not in neg_indexes], 2)

print(neg_test)
print(pos_test)
```

Output:

```
['Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF10_AC.png,0.3,-0.95', 'Stimuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces/AF06_AC.png,1,-1.55']
['Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AM02_HO.png,-0.6,1.65', 'Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces/AF11_HC.png,-0.9,1.3']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! One quick follow up question: how would this change to include other indices within ```re.search```? So there are also indices like ```CFD-WF-015-014-A``` and ```004_o_m_a_a```. I updated my question with lists including these indices for reference.

Comment: I've updated the `parse_index()` function to account for some of these different variations.